# gacutil is not a valid win32 application?

Tags: .net, gac, gacutil

I registered `Mono.WebServer.dll` in the GAC with:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SDK\v2.0\Bin\gacutil.exe
```

Then I wanted to install an additional assembly in the GAC and I got:

> gacutil is not a valid win32 application.

I used the same gacutil both times... I restarted and the problem persists.

Comment: Uh-oh, you triggered the self-destruct sequence.

Comment: Mono? That's a virus.  I wasn't aware that it could cross over from humans to PCs.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Indeed, seems so. But I have lately had a lot of issues with corruption, just don't know why installing Mono.Webserver in the GAC triggered it.

Comment: Get your machine stable again.  Good luck.

Comment: @mootinator: True, but it's also Spanish and means 'ape'. See http://primates.ximian.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gacutil is bundled with .Net SDK, not with visual studio. Maybe you should try to re install .Net SDK if it needs to and load gacutil from this path : C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bin (make sure the version number matches your system)

Comment: Thank you - was good advice. Now it works again. What I don't yet understand is why I could install the .NET SDK when it was already installed, and not uninstalled.